# Adding in code snippets/partials on a page

Tags: php, module, laravel-5

How do I include snippets, or partials in pages in Laravel 5? In node/angular, it's quite easy to simply load different modules and such on a page.

For example, on my home page, I'm looping through some data:

```
<h1>Home</h1>

@if (count($practice))
    <ul>
        @foreach($practice as $val)
            <li>{{ $val }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

[image]

---

If I include the login snippet on the page, it covers up the rest of the data:

```
<h1>Home</h1>

@if (count($practice))
    <ul>
        @foreach($practice as $val)
            <li>{{ $val }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif

@include('auth.login')
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to be more of a CSS question, have you checked the html source of your page and verified that the ul and li values are being returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include it in a new row :

```
<h1>Home</h1>

@if (count($practice))
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul>
        @foreach($practice as $val)
            <li>{{ $val }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @include('auth.login')
    </div>
</div>
```